# How to distribute array elements into another array while no array has more than 1 element that the other?

Tags: java

i need to distribute x number of students from an array and add them to n number of array but no array can have more than 1 from the other for example:
17 students into 3 arrays
the first two arrays will hold 6 and the last one will have 5

i tried to do this but it is not consistent :

```
double x = 17;
double n = 3;
double theSizeOfEachArray = x%n;
String[] array1;
String[] array2;
String[] array3;
if (theSizeOfEachArray ==0){
array1 =new String[x/n];
array2 =new String[x/n];
array3 =new String[x/n];
}
if (theSizeOfEachArray ==1)
array1 =new String[Math.ceil(x/n)];
array2 =new String[Math.floor(x/n)];
array3 =new String[Math.floor(x/n)];
if (theSizeOfEachArray ==2)
array1 =new String[Math.ceil(x/n)];
array2 =new String[Math.ceil(x/n)];
array3 =new String[Math.floor(x/n)];
....
```

it will only work if the number of arrays are 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
        int x = 17;
        int n = 3;
        int theSizeOfEachArray = x%n;
        
        
        String[] array1 = new String[x / n + ((theSizeOfEachArray > 0) ? 1 : 0)];
        
        if(theSizeOfEachArray > 0)
            theSizeOfEachArray--;
        
        String[] array2 = new String[x / n + ((theSizeOfEachArray > 0) ? 1 : 0)];
        
        if(theSizeOfEachArray > 0)
            theSizeOfEachArray--;
        
        String[] array3 = new String[x / n + ((theSizeOfEachArray > 0) ? 1 : 0)];
```

I switched to using ints instead of doubles because they are easier to deal with.

Basically, on each array initialization, I check to see if there is still a remainder and if there is, add 1. Then I decrement the remainder if necessary. In this particular case, I can even condense the array initialization and decrement into one line of code:

```
        int x = 17;
        int n = 3;
        int theSizeOfEachArray = x%n;
        
        
        String[] array1 = new String[x / n + ((theSizeOfEachArray-- > 0) ? 1 : 0)];
        
        String[] array2 = new String[x / n + ((theSizeOfEachArray-- > 0) ? 1 : 0)];
        
        String[] array3 = new String[x / n + ((theSizeOfEachArray-- > 0) ? 1 : 0)];
```

`((theSizeOfEachArray-- > 0) ? 1 : 0)` is a ternary expression. Basically, if the condition is true, then the "1" between "?" and ":" is returned. Otherwise, the "0" is.